# Change the Arrangement order of items in RecyclerView Retrieved From Firebase PopulateView

Tags: java, android, firebase, collections, android-recyclerview

I am creating an chat App And I am having a problem swapping the order list of the Items in RecyclerView Which is Retrieved from Firebase populateView Method 
Here is my chatlist Activity

```
    mAdappyter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, CViewHolder>(User.class,R.layout.chatlist,CViewHolder.class,mDatabaseReference) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final CViewHolder viewHolder, User model, final int position) {



            viewHolder.mGroupName.setText(model.getmName());








            mImagesReferences = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UPhoto").child(model.getmName());
            mLast = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Last").child(model.getmName());
            mTime = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("TIME").child(model.getmName());





            mImagesReferences.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    String url = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();

                    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(url).into(viewHolder.mPhoto);


                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });



            mTime.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {


                    String lala = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();

                    viewHolder.mLastTime.setText(lala);



                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });




            mLast.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),dataSnapshot.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    String time = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                    // String last = dataSnapshot.child("mUser").getValue().toString();

                    viewHolder.mMessage.setText(time);





                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {



                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });



            viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {



                   String naam = viewHolder.mGroupName.getText().toString();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("messy",naam);
                    startActivity(intent);






                   // Toast.makeText(getApplication(),""+position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                }
            });



        }
    };



    mListView.setAdapter(mAdappyter);
    mAdappyterbitch.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

So this is How I populate My RecyclerView And I can't Swap the elements in it using

```
     Collections.swap(List,2,3);
```

Functions Beacuse I don't Have a List in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter to use and swap items , It works Fine when i use an ArrayAdapter and Arraylist which passes only one elements .

Answer (score 1):

You can use getSnapshots to get list Items. This return FirebaseArray. If you want to use in Collections.swap you could use:

```
public List<User> getListSnapshot() {
        List modelList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (User model : super.getSnapshots()) {
            modelList.add(model);
        }

        return modelList;
}

List list = getListSnapshot();

Collections.swap(list,2,3);
```